# Foreach to change html element to display different tabs

Tags: php

So I have the following code:

```html
<div class="level-right pr-2">
    <div class="level-item">
        <?php foreach ($change_log->get_update() as $update): ?>
            <?php if ($update === 'New'): ?>
                <span class="tag is-primary mr-1"><?= $update ?></span>
            <?php elseif ($update === 'Update'): ?>
                <span class="tag is-info mr-1"><?= $update ?></span>
            <?php elseif ($update === 'Change'): ?>
                <span class="tag is-warning mr-1"><?= $update ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

.. Which renders different buttons for different `$update` variable. The `$change_log->get_update()` will always return just a single array value, where I loop through.

The above works just fine, but..

Would someone know a way to do the following smarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<?php 
$status = [
  "New"    => "is-primary",
  "Update" => "is-info",
  "Change" => "is-warning"
];
?>
```

```
<div class="level-right pr-2">
    <div class="level-item">
        <?php foreach ($change_log->get_update() as $update): ?>
           <span class="tag <?=$status[$update]?> mr-1"><?= $update ?></span>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will look cleaner and nicer.

Comment: This works man! Appreciate it, something to note for future items :)